# tkinter Как можно реализовать сохранение результата (игры)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tkinter Как можно реализовать сохранение результата (игры)? Есть приложение, где надо кликать на кружочки и получать очки, и мне нужно, что бы при последующем запуске программы лучший результат должен сохранятся. Сама программа есть, но как выполнить задачу я не знаю.(Я совсем новичок, не кидайтесь палками пж ,если что то неправильно сформулировал или глупый вопрос)(за лучший результат отвечают функции BestScore и Score)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import math
import math as m
import random

#Начало блока окна
root = Tk()
root.geometry('960x540')
root.title("ReacPicker v1.0")
#Конец блока окна

#Начало блока переменных
colors = ['red','orange','green','pink', 'lavender', 'cyan']
instr = "Жми играть и полетел тыкать по кружочкам! Один кружочек - 10 очков."
zach = "gg "
sc = 0
bestScore = 0
timer_running = False  # запущен ли таймер
default_seconds = 60  # изначальное положение(только секунды указывать)
timer_seconds = default_seconds  # текущее положение таймера, сек
radius = 13
#Конец блока переменных

#Начало блока функций
   #Начало Таймера
def timer_start_pause():
    global timer_running
    timer_running = not timer_running  # работа или пауза
    if timer_running:  # работа
        timer_tick()
def timer_reset():
    global timer_running, timer_seconds
    timer_running = False  # стоп
    timer_seconds = default_seconds  # изначальное положение
    show_timer()
def timer_tick():
    global timer_seconds
    if timer_running and timer_seconds:
        label.after(1000, timer_tick)  # перезапустить через 1 сек
        # уменьшить таймер
        timer_seconds -= 1
        show_timer()
def show_timer():
    '''отобразить таймер'''
    m = timer_seconds//60
    s = timer_seconds-m*60
    label['text'] = '%02d:%02d' % (m, s)
    if m == 0:
        if s == 0:
            Win()
   #Конец Таймера

def Instruct():
    messagebox.showinfo("Справка", instr)
def Zachem():
    messagebox.showinfo("Справка", zach)
def Score():
    global sc
    sc += 10
    scoreLB.config(text = "Счет: " + str(sc))
    BestScore()
def BestScore():
    global bestScore, sc
    if sc > bestScore:
        bestScore = sc
        labelBS.config(text = "лучший: " + str(bestScore))
def Start():
    global sc
    timer_reset()
    sc -= 10
    Krujki()
    buttonPlay['state'] = 'disabled'
    show_timer()
    timer_start_pause()
    labelWIN.config(text='', bg="white")
    labelLOSE.config(text = '', bg = "white")
def Krujki():
    global a,b,r, bestScore
    holst.delete(ALL)
    a = random.randint(5, 640)
    b = random.randint(5, 480)
    r = radius
    holst.create_oval(a-r,b-r,a+r,b+r,fill = random.choice(colors), width=1, tag="circle")
    root.after(100)
    Score()
def click(event):
    global x, y, l
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    l = m.sqrt(pow((a - x), 2) + pow((b - y), 2))
    if l > r:
        Lose()
    else:
        Krujki()
        print("Попал")
def Win():
    global sc, bestScore
    holst.delete('circle')
    buttonPlay['state'] = 'active'
    print("а ты не плох твой результат: " + str(sc))
    labelWIN.config(text = 'Твой результат: ' + str(sc), bg="white", fg="#EDA7AC", font = ("Ubuntu", 35))
    timer_reset()
def Lose():
    global sc, bestScore
    holst.delete('circle')
    print("лох")
    buttonPlay['state'] = 'active'
    labelLOSE.config(text = 'Ну ты и лох, попробуй еще, счет: ' + str(sc), bg="white", fg="#EDA7AC", font = ("Ubuntu", 23))
    timer_reset()
    sc = 0
def Minute1():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 60
def Minute2():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 120
def Minute30():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 30
def Minute10():
    global default_seconds
    default_seconds = 10
#Конец блока функций


#Начало блока меню
menu1 = Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menu1)
menu1.add_command(label = "Инструкция", command=Instruct)
menu1.add_command(label = "О программе", command=Zachem)
#Конец блока меню

#Начало блока объектов
holst = Canvas(root, width=670, height=500, bg='white')
label1 = Label(root, text = 'ReacPicker v1.0', font = ("Ubuntu", 14))
label = Label(root, font = ("Ubuntu", 22))
labelWIN = Label(root, text = '', bg="white")
labelLOSE = Label(root, text = '', fg="white")
labelBS = Label(root, text = "лучший: ", font = ("Ubuntu", 16))
buttonPlay = Button(root, text = 'Играть', font = 30,height=5, width=25,  command=Start)
scoreLB = Label(root, text = "Счет: " + str(sc), font = ("Ubuntu", 22))
button1 = Button(root, text = '1 мин.', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute1)
button2 = Button(root, text = '2 мин.', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute2)
button30 = Button(root, text = '30 сек', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute30)
button10 = Button(root, text = '10 сек', font = 30,height=4, width=6,  command=Minute10)
#конец блока объектов

#Начало блока размещения
holst.place(x= 10, y= 10)
label.place(x= 700,y= 400 )
label1.place(x= 700, y= 20)
labelLOSE.place(x= 50,y= 450)
labelWIN.place(x= 50,y= 50)
labelBS.place(x= 700, y= 85)
buttonPlay.place(x= 700, y= 130)
scoreLB.place(x= 700,y= 450)
button1.place(x= 830, y= 235)
button2.place(x= 895, y= 235)
button30.place(x= 765, y= 235)
button10.place(x= 700, y= 235)
#Конец блока размещения
holst.bind('<Button-1>', click)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импортируйте модуль

```
import configparser
```

Напишите функцию или добавьте в существующую открытие файла и запись в него результатов

```
f = open('config.ini', 'w')
f.write("score = sc" '\n')
f.write("bestscore = bestScore" '\n')
f.close()
```

Если вам нужно получить результаты при запуске то используйте

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
```

Comment: Записывать данные в конфиг лучше тоже через configparser

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, записывать результат, который необходимо сохранить в текстовый документ, а при запуске программы просто считывать информацию из этого файла

Answer (score 0):

Более рациональным решением я нашел создать простой файл .txt, добавить в функцию BestScore вслучае if sc > bestScore(не забыть добавить file в global функции) :

```
file = open('1.txt', 'w')
file.write(str(bestScore))
file.close()
```

после записи в 1.txt bestScore я добавил вне функций в конце файла

```
file = open('gh.txt', 'r')
bestScore = int(fileW.read())
labelBS.config(text = "лучший: " + str(bestScore))
```

что бы при запуске лейбел сразу обновлялся на bestScore из файла